# Angular 7 Can´t send header in get web service with map

Tags: angular

The error is simple. I don´t know how exactly send a headers in http.get method. I think the error appear when trying to map response. So anybody know what is the correct way to send a header in webservice and map it?

```
const httpOptions = {
  headers: new HttpHeaders({
    "Authorization":
   "TOKEN"
    })
};

this.http
  .get("URL", httpOptions)
  .map(this.extractData)
  .subscribe(data => {
    this.dtTrigger.next();
  });


  private extractData(res:Response) {
    const body = res.json();
    return body['body'] || {};
```

The error in the console is:

> Type 'HttpHeaders' is missing the following properties from type
>   'Headers': forEach, values, toJSON, entries, mayBeSetNormalizedName

**UPDATE 2:** Imports added

```
import { Component, OnInit } from "@angular/core";
import { HttpClient, Response } from "@angular/http";
import { NgForm } from "@angular/forms";
```

**UPDATE 3**: Full Example of code.

**https://l-lin.github.io/angular-datatables/#/basic/angular-way**

I need to add header with token in `this.http.get('data/data.json')`

Comment: what error are you getting?

Comment: Type 'HttpHeaders' is missing the following properties from type 'Headers': forEach, values, toJSON, entries, mayBeSetNormalizedName

Comment: Did you tried defining yout httpHeader with single quotes?

Comment: And please add your imports

Comment: Question updated.

Comment: change .get("URL", httpOptions) to .get("URL", {headers: httpOptions})

Comment: provide a minimal verifiable reproducible example (you can use https://stackblitz.com/). the snippets you provided don't look like angular 7 (for example @angular/http does not exist in that version, it's @angular/common/http and HttpClient, not Http).

Comment: I update question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The example you provided must be from an earlier version of Angular. In Angular 7 you'd do it like this:

in app.module.ts:

`import { HttpClientModule } from '@angular/common/http';`

and in @NgModule:
`imports: [ HttpClientModule ]`

then in your component:
`import { HttpClient, HttpHeaders } from '@angular/common/http';`

forget about map, HttpClient uses generic calls and publishes the right type:

`this.http.get<Person[]>('url', options).subscribe(persons => this.persons = persons /* ... */);`

Comment: I try something similar to your code but can't iterate values in HTML.

Answer (score 0):

```
const httpOptions = {
  headers: new HttpHeaders({
    "Authorization":
   "TOKEN"
    })
};

this.http
  .get("URL"+id, httpOptions) 
  .subscribe(data => {
    this.elementosDatatable = data['body']['list'];
    console.log(this.elementosDatatable);
    this.dtTrigger.next();
  });
```

Return

```
(2) [{…}, {…}]
0: {id: 1, description: "Test1", check: 1}
1: {id: 2, description: "test2", check: 0}
length: 2
__proto__: Array(0)
```

In HTML try to

```
<tr *ngFor="let elementosDatatable of elemento">
                <td>{{elemento.id}}</td>
              </tr>
```

But foreach loop in html doesn´t return data, so now, what is the error?

Comment: you got it switched. it should be "let elemento of elementosDatatable"